# MatrixBase::sqrt() not working in Eigen3

Tags: c++, visual-studio, eigen3

Hello there everybody :),

I was trying to use an unsupported feature of Eigen3 to get the square root of each element of a Matrix ([MatrixBase::sqrt()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/unsupported/group__MatrixFunctions__Module.html#matrixbase_sqrt)). However, Visual Studio is giving me the following error every time I use the previously stated funtion: `Use of undefined type 'Eigen::MatrixSquareRootReturnValue<Derived>'`

This is what I am doing:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd ScalesM(3,3);
ScalesM << 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9;
ScalesM = ScalesM.sqrt();
```

Any sort of help will be highly appreciated. Have a wonderful day!

Comment: Compiles for me without problem on Clang and GCC ([full example](https://hastebin.com/eziwucabig.cpp)).  However, this code cannot work because to take the square root the matrix has to be invertible which this one is not (for computational reasons the eigenvalues have to be positive as well).

Comment: Did you remember to: `#include <unsupported/Eigen/MatrixFunctions>`?

Answer (score 5):

You are looking at the wrong documentation. Square root of a matrix is not the same as square root of each element of a matrix. If you want element-wise operations then you should use [Eigen Array](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html) instead of Eigen Matrix. You can always convert from matrix to array using [.array()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html#title6) function and from array to matrix using [.matrix()](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialArrayClass.html#title6). So the correct documentation for your use case is [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1ArrayBase.html#adbe7fe792be28d5293ae6a586b36c028).

Your code should be

```
ScalesM.array().sqrt();
```

Or as @Henri Menke suggested in the comment, you can use

```
ScalesM.cwiseSqrt();
```

Comment: You can also use [`ScalesM.cwiseSqrt()`](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/classEigen_1_1MatrixBase.html#a9a49e9a834666aa86e80f55b39926e04).

Comment: I didn't know about that. Thanks!